# Запятая перед "в связи с которым"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

Это основной момент в связи с которым удобен переход на мобильные приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Запятая нужна.**

Это сложносочинённое предложение с придаточным определительным, присоединенным с помощью союзного слова *который*. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится запятая. Союзное слово *который* может находиться не только в начале, но и в середине придаточной части. Например:

**Мы подошли к реке, правый берег которой зарос густым колючим кустарником.**